# notification alert on intel xdk not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel

**how to use alert method on intel xdk?**

1. i try use this script but not working on my real device ( only work on emulate and test intel xdk)

> intel.xdk.notification.alert("Hammertime!","STOP","Can\'t Touch This");

2. this script also does not work ( only work on emulate and test intel xdk)

> navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName]);

*#note : i have added plugins ( for number 1 --> include plugin --> dialogs (notification) plugin , and for number 2 --> third party plugin --> org.apache.cordova.dialogs )*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the Intel XDK alerts, why don't you use the built in javascript

```
alert();
```

or use the jquery ui dialog. It also has a modal confirmation capability.
 Demo: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation 
Custom Dialog only Download: http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=1111101000010100000000000000000000000 
and Jquery itself: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

 Dialog API: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

With all this, you should be able to make a jquery modal confirmation dialog.